# Nginx Rewrite rules + CSS & JS

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, webserver

I'm using Nginx and some rewrite rules mostly for pretty urls. Here are my rewrite rules:

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$                /index.php?module=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ /index.php?module=$1&pid=$2 last;
```

The rewrite rules are working, but they are also affecting my .css and .js files. My .css and .js files are in a folder called /inc/static in my webserver root.

Example:
http://example.com/signup/member

Now the path to my .css and .js files also changes to /signup/inc/static.

I could use a static subdomain for .css and .js files, which would probably solve my issue but I am also using https with certificates so that I would get a warning if I include files from https://static.example.com/js/jquery.js for example, since the certificate would not be signed.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Dave, I know it was year ago you posted this but as this is still not solved may I ask if you found solution for this problem? Thanks in advance, Greg.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using relative address when requesting your CSS/JS files, e.g.:

```
<script src="inc/static/myscript.js" />
```

You need to use absolute addresses, i.e. with the preceeding slash:

```
<script src="/inc/static/myscript.js" />
```

Comment: I'm playing around with nginx and found similar issue and certainly absolute paths do not solve the problem. Do you have any ideas how to form rewrite rules to allow CSS/JS files through?